# is Java WatchService per JVM or can an app start multiple?

Tags: java, watchservice

```
FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
```

Does that create a new watchService or just give a singleton object?

it says:

> @return  a new watch service

Some post I read made me think there might only be 1 and so if you do a `.take()` or `.poll()` one thread might get another threads watchKey event. I thought maybe I need to use one but now I am not so sure because I do have 2 or so running and they seemed to work but I have not explicitly tested it.

Anyone know if you can use multiple watchServices in one app?

Comment: "New" suggests it creates a new object each time; that us the convention in method naming, but that convention is not universally followed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the source code here it seems that each time it is called it returns a new [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html)

```
class WindowsFileSystem
    extends FileSystem
{
..............................
..............................
@Override
    public WatchService newWatchService()
        throws IOException
    {
        return new WindowsWatchService(this);
    }
}
```

**`this`** here refers to the [WindowsFileSystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) object ( I am checking this on Windows JVM )  which is static variable and hence single per JVM

```
public final class FileSystems {
    private FileSystems() {
    }
.................
.................
public static FileSystem getDefault() {
        return DefaultFileSystemHolder.defaultFileSystem;
    }

}
```

So we can conclude that the [FileSystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) object is global, however WatchService can be as many as created - all having reference to the global FileSystem.

Comment: Where are you getting that low source code, openJdk or something? I click in (netbeans) IDE and I get : 
public abstract class FileSystem
    implements Closeable      and
public interface WatchService
    extends Closeable

Comment: Yes that is OpenJDK.